# Hg: extension search path

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-extension

I want to use a special extension, but for certain reasons I want to avoid to modify my Mercurial installation and touch existing `Mercurial.ini` or `.hg/hgrc` files. Usually, I invoke a command like

```
hg --config extensions.hgext.foo=c:\path\to\my\extension.py ...
```

If I would write just

```
hg --config extensions.hgext.foo=extension.py ...
```

where Mercurial would search for `extension.py`? Is there a way to configure an environment variable where I can add/set `c:\path\to\my` path, so Mercurial would find `extensions.py` without specifying the full path?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the windows cmd line interface, you could wrap the entire config line into the cmd window's local environment var:

```
SET enablefoo=--config extensions.hgext.foo=c:\path\to\my\extension.py
```

Then you could turn it on for any given command by:

```
hg %enablefoo% foo -r tip
```

Note that this is using the local environment variable to do some inline substituion before hg is called; hg is not affected or altered at all and isn't "searching" for anything.

Comment: I'm not using the Windows command line, but launch the command from an application.